# Php script stops after long time and no error could be found on the error_log

Tags: php

Im running a long php script which handles large amounts of data.

The problem is that the script suddenly stops and no exception is thrown or could be found on the error_log.
I have set the display_errors and the error_logging to 1 in the .ini config file.

Few more details:
1) The scripts executes the 'file_get_contents' function for many times.
2) The scripts contains recursion  when the file_get_contents fails.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What about execution time limit in php.ini?

Comment: The script runs for several hours before crashing

Answer (score 0):

It might have hit the max execution time.

```
set_time_limit(0); // to increase the timelimit to infinity
```

Comment: I have already set this param. The script runs for several hours before crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Error loging configs are different depending on your hosting environment. I'd first verify that you're editing the right php.ini file. Take a look at your phpinfo output and make sure that those params are indeed set and check the path/file for where errors are being logged to. Sometimes it goes to the apache error log, other times it can be sent to a dedicated php log. Are you able to get any error output if you purposefully create a syntax error? You might also consider looking in your syslog to see if there's anything there.

Comment: The phpinfo is well defined. I get errors/warnings/notices when using a syntax error.

Comment: I should mention that the script is executing the file_get_contents function and i think it might be related to this function failing.

Comment: Where can i find the syslog?Im using the bluehost as the hosting server.